# How to get all designs from CouchDB?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, couchdb

I am writing my application on CouchDB and Angular technology.

And for calling all documents I use this function:

```
getCommsHistory() {
        let defer = this.$q.defer();
        this.localCommsHistoryDB.allDocs({include_docs: true, group: true}).then((doc) => {
            defer.resolve(doc.rows.map(row => row.doc));
        }, () => {
            defer.reject();
        });
        return defer.promise;
    }
```

How can i call all designs?

Comment: You want to learn about the `startkey` and `endkey` parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `startkey` and `endkey`.

Like that:

```
GET /dbname/_all_docs?startkey="_design/"&endkey="_design0"&include_docs=true
```